# Manually adjusting positions of UI elements in Xcode's storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

Instead of having to use xcodes constraints, which I can never get to work right, is there a way to manually set where UI elements are on the screen? I noticed that if I'm on the attributes bar for the view controller, I can set `simulated metrics`'s `size` to any iphone size I want.

Then I can position the UI elements on the screen where I please. When I build and run, it always mimics exactly what I set up. However, it only works for the particular size of the iphone I specified. Is there a way to do all the sizes manually without making several xcode projects?

Thanks!

Comment: You should show an example that doesn't work and learn how to apply constraints properly, not how to avoid constraints...

Comment: This question is too broad and unclear.  The only reason why it hasn't been closed yet is because of the bounty attached.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're going to want to learn how to properly use constraints. The approach you're trying to do would have been okay when there was only one screen size, but now we have three different sizes of iPad, two watch sizes and four different iPhone sizes. Here's a link to a tutorial from Ray Wenderlich (he has some pretty good tutorials to get you started n a wide variety of things). https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

The auto layout in storyboard on Xcode 7 isn't my favorite, but when Xcode 8 comes out it provides device specific sizes for views that makes auto layout much easier. So maybe Xcode 8 will provide a better solution to your problem!

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple other solution that is not as good as constraints.

1) Use `frame` property of views to place them

2) Use size classes to do different placement for iPad iPhone etc

3) Use suggested constraints - you are placing views and than you can give XCode possibility to create constraints for you suggesting what you want from your views placement.

Comment: So are you saying that I can't manually set each item in the storyboard for iPhone 3.5, 4, 4.7, 5.5 inch?

Comment: Yes you cant set it without constraints to work fine